# C# - Can a Method Examine Another Method's Use of a Parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a variety of methods that use a configuration object to fill in placeholders in a template. Different methods use different subsets of properties of the configuration object. I'd like an easy way to check that all the properties a given method uses are present in a given config object.

Right now I have a method like this:

```
private static void ValidateConfiguration(CustomerConfiguration config, params string[] properties)
```

This has the maintenance disadvantage that it relies on a separate set of strings for the properties used. What I'd love to do is have the validation method look at the calling method and see what properties of the config object are being accessed. Can this be done?

(I could also wrap String.Replace() in a method that checks for nulls, but that's less fun.)

Answer (score 0):

A type safe way to handle your problem would be to implement several interfaces with different meaningful subsets of properties. My understanding is that the presence/absence of the properties in your case depends on the type of configuration object and is dynamic.

you could use a signature like that

```cs
ValidateConfiguration<T>(CustomerConfiguration config)
```

where `T` represent the interface and use reflection to list the required properties. While it would be practically impossible to parse the code of a method to infer its usages of a data structure, reflection on types (to extract properties) is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

> Different methods use different subsets of properties of the configuration object.

If you're only creating one instance of the configuration property, then the properties it needs to have are whichever ones are going to be used by any method. In other words, if at least one method needs that property, then the object needs that property.

In that case there's no need to validate it in relation to individual methods that need it. All of its properties need to be populated because they're all needed somewhere. If they're not needed anywhere, you can delete them.

Then, instead of validating that object based on the needs of a particular method, you validate it once, perhaps at startup. All of the properties are needed, so if they haven't been specified then the application just can't run. (Sometimes it's good to include defaults in your configuration object. You might have one property that you want to be able to configure, but in real life it's never going to change.)

If you're creating different instances of the same object for use in different methods and you only want to populate certain properties then it's better not to do that. Just create more granular objects for different scenarios containing all the properties you need.

What frequently happens is this: We have an object with lots of properties and we only use a few of them, so we populate those properties and pass the object to a method. The other properties are null.

Then, someone modifying that method decides that they need another property, so they try to use it, and they're surprised to find out that it's null. Then they have to go back and trace where that object was created and figure out what is populated or not. That's confusing and time-consuming.

Unless fields are entirely optional and it doesn't matter whether they are populated or not, we don't want to find ourselves looking at an object with lots of properties and guessing which ones have been populated because individual methods that create the object "know" which properties other classes do or don't need.

Comment: Both this answer and Samuel Vidal's answer basically referral that I am being lazy. Which is quite true - this is an internal tool, and I'm trying to keep it flexible and easy to modify, at the expense of making it not foolproof. It sounds like what I was asking for may not be possible in .NET.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't make that judgment or assumption. I don't presume to know anything about the context in which any question comes up. I just try to answer. That being said, even if it is just an internal app I'd probably follow most of the same practices as with any other, because those internal apps grow and then over the years we end up maintaining them like anything else.